# How to handle Stripe failed payments between subscription renewal vs upgrade?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

**Upgrade Workflow**

A customer has one subscription (*single* or *team*), and the ability to *add additional team members* (which updates the subscription's quantity).

If a customer currently has a single plan they can upgrade to a team plan. If anyone on a team plan needs additional seats, they simply change the quantity of their subscription.

I have webhooks currently set up for: `customer.subscription.updated`, `customer.subscription.deleted`, `invoice.paid`, and `invoice.payment_failed`.

**Goal**

- If a payment fails during a subscription's renewal, I would like the subscription to be canceled after the retry limit is hit.
- If a payment fails during a subscription upgrade, I would like the previous subscription to remain with no cancellation.

**Problem**

Currently, in the dashboard, I have *Subscription Status* (found in Manage Failed Payments) set to cancel subscription if all retries failed.

Will this cancel the subscription in the case of all invoices, that have reached the retry limit, such as for renewals (invoice object's `billing_reason: "subscription_cycle"`) and upgrades (`billing_reason: "subscription_update"`)?

If yes I'll need to turn this off, but what is the standard way to handle such a scenario through my webhooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got this pretty close to solved from you question.  The `invoice.payment_failed` event is what you are looking for. So here's how I would approach this:

### [Dashboard Settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic)

Either

- Deactivate the setting to cancel the subscription if the invoice payment fails
- Or keep it but set to the max number of days (15) as a fail safe in case your other logic fails to catch a situation where you *should* cancel the subscription

### Webhook Handling

If the event type is `invoice.payment_failed`, inspect `invoice.billing_reason` to determine whether it was in response to a renewal or an update.  For either process, you can access the subscription ID in `invoice.subscription`.

```py
if invoice.billing_reason == "subscription_cycle":
    # Renewal Payment Failure - Cancel the subscription for this customer
    stripe.Subscription.delete(invoice.subscription)
    # Take other measures (like emailing the customer)
    ...

elif invoice.billing_reason == "subscription_update":
    # Upgrade Payment Failure - downgrade subscription
    ...
```

Apologies for the Python, it's the language I'm most comfortable in

Comment: Thanks @RyanM I ended up using a similar approach! I think I was just having trouble wrapping my head around the behavior of the dashboard setting. Wasn't sure if the setting meant that a subscription would be canceled on every failed invoice. Stripe support confirmed that it does. Thank you for your answer though!